# Find local maxima in grayscale image using OpenCV

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, mathematical-optimization

Does anybody know how to find the local maxima in a grayscale `IPL_DEPTH_8U` image using OpenCV? HarrisCorner mentions something like that but I'm actually not interested in corners ... 
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the morphology Dilation operation in OpenCV find out the local maxima in a 3x3 or a user-defined kernel and set the pixels to this max value? So this could be modified to your purpose.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you want to use the

```
MinMaxLoc(arr, mask=NULL)-> (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc)
Finds global minimum and maximum in array or subarray
```

function on you image

Comment: actually that looks for the global. I'd prefer local (regional) like Matlab's imregionmax() function.

Comment: You can use cvSetImageROI and cvResetImageROI calls to define the subregion over which you're searching. Then, fabrizio's suggestion would work just fine.

Comment: Before running this function, consider blurring the image if you would like to obtain local peaks.

Comment: @peakxu It's actually not that easy use the global MinMaxLoc function to find local extrema in combination with some ROI. How do you set the subregion? In a sliding window manner? MinMaxLoc will always return a minimum and maximum. A border pixel in the ROI might be a global maximum within the ROI, but the next pixel outside the ROI might have an even larger value.

Answer (score 8):

A pixel is considered a local maximum if it is equal to the maximum value in a 'local' neighborhood. The function below captures this property in two lines of code.

To deal with pixels on 'plateaus' (value equal to their neighborhood) one can use the local minimum property, since plateaus pixels are equal to their local minimum. The rest of the code filters out those pixels.

```
void non_maxima_suppression(const cv::Mat& image, cv::Mat& mask, bool remove_plateaus) {
    // find pixels that are equal to the local neighborhood not maximum (including 'plateaus')
    cv::dilate(image, mask, cv::Mat());
    cv::compare(image, mask, mask, cv::CMP_GE);

    // optionally filter out pixels that are equal to the local minimum ('plateaus')
    if (remove_plateaus) {
        cv::Mat non_plateau_mask;
        cv::erode(image, non_plateau_mask, cv::Mat());
        cv::compare(image, non_plateau_mask, non_plateau_mask, cv::CMP_GT);
        cv::bitwise_and(mask, non_plateau_mask, mask);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code gives 'connected' results, which is weird since we are looking for local maxima; two maxima cannot be connected if you ask me. Even if i increase the kernel size.

Comment: `cv::CMP_GE` can also be replaced with `cv::CMP_EQ` (the value must match exactly the local maxima to be the local maxima)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple trick. The idea is to dilate with a kernel that contains a hole in the center. After the dilate operation, each pixel is replaced with the maximum of it's neighbors (using a 5 by 5 neighborhood in this example), **excluding** the original pixel.

```
Mat1b kernelLM(Size(5, 5), 1u);
kernelLM.at<uchar>(2, 2) = 0u;
Mat imageLM;
dilate(image, imageLM, kernelLM);
Mat1b localMaxima = (image > imageLM);
```

Comment: what if one neighbor has the same maximum value?

Answer (score 5):

Actually after I posted the code above I wrote a better and very very faster one ..
The code above suffers even for a 640x480 picture..
I optimized it and  now it is very very fast even for 1600x1200 pic.
Here is the code :

```
void localMaxima(cv::Mat src,cv::Mat &dst,int squareSize)
{
if (squareSize==0)
{
    dst = src.clone();
    return;
}

Mat m0;
dst = src.clone();
Point maxLoc(0,0);

//1.Be sure to have at least 3x3 for at least looking at 1 pixel close neighbours
//  Also the window must be <odd>x<odd>
SANITYCHECK(squareSize,3,1);
int sqrCenter = (squareSize-1)/2;

//2.Create the localWindow mask to get things done faster
//  When we find a local maxima we will multiply the subwindow with this MASK
//  So that we will not search for those 0 values again and again
Mat localWindowMask = Mat::zeros(Size(squareSize,squareSize),CV_8U);//boolean
localWindowMask.at<unsigned char>(sqrCenter,sqrCenter)=1;

//3.Find the threshold value to threshold the image
    //this function here returns the peak of histogram of picture
    //the picture is a thresholded picture it will have a lot of zero values in it
    //so that the second boolean variable says :
    //  (boolean) ? "return peak even if it is at 0" : "return peak discarding 0"
int thrshld =  maxUsedValInHistogramData(dst,false);
threshold(dst,m0,thrshld,1,THRESH_BINARY);

//4.Now delete all thresholded values from picture
dst = dst.mul(m0);

//put the src in the middle of the big array
for (int row=sqrCenter;row<dst.size().height-sqrCenter;row++)
    for (int col=sqrCenter;col<dst.size().width-sqrCenter;col++)
    {
        //1.if the value is zero it can not be a local maxima
        if (dst.at<unsigned char>(row,col)==0)
            continue;
        //2.the value at (row,col) is not 0 so it can be a local maxima point
        m0 =  dst.colRange(col-sqrCenter,col+sqrCenter+1).rowRange(row-sqrCenter,row+sqrCenter+1);
        minMaxLoc(m0,NULL,NULL,NULL,&maxLoc);
        //if the maximum location of this subWindow is at center
        //it means we found the local maxima
        //so we should delete the surrounding values which lies in the subWindow area
        //hence we will not try to find if a point is at localMaxima when already found a neighbour was
        if ((maxLoc.x==sqrCenter)&&(maxLoc.y==sqrCenter))
        {
            m0 = m0.mul(localWindowMask);
                            //we can skip the values that we already made 0 by the above function
            col+=sqrCenter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can always edit your own post and even if you two answers, you can post them separately.

Comment: I just realized that :) thanks for the tip.. but is it possible to delete the one above?

Comment: A moderator can delete that.
You can flag it for a moderator to consider.

Comment: awesome.. thanks a ton..but although I can flag this one the other post doesn't have a flag option below :(

Comment: @DogaSiyli what is SANITYCHECK?

Answer (score 5):

The following listing is a function similar to Matlab's "imregionalmax". It looks for at most **nLocMax** local maxima above **threshold**, where the found local maxima are at least **minDistBtwLocMax** pixels apart. It returns the actual number of local maxima found. Notice that it uses OpenCV's **minMaxLoc** to find global maxima. It is "opencv-self-contained" except for the (easy to implement) function **vdist**, which computes the (euclidian) distance between points (r,c) and (row,col).

**input** is one-channel CV_32F matrix, and **locations** is nLocMax (rows) by 2 (columns) CV_32S matrix.

```html
int imregionalmax(Mat input, int nLocMax, float threshold, float minDistBtwLocMax, Mat locations)
{
    Mat scratch = input.clone();
    int nFoundLocMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nLocMax; i++) {
        Point location;
        double maxVal;
        minMaxLoc(scratch, NULL, &maxVal, NULL, &location);
        if (maxVal > threshold) {
            nFoundLocMax += 1;
            int row = location.y;
            int col = location.x;
            locations.at<int>(i,0) = row;
            locations.at<int>(i,1) = col;
            int r0 = (row-minDistBtwLocMax > -1 ? row-minDistBtwLocMax : 0);
            int r1 = (row+minDistBtwLocMax < scratch.rows ? row+minDistBtwLocMax : scratch.rows-1);
            int c0 = (col-minDistBtwLocMax > -1 ? col-minDistBtwLocMax : 0);
            int c1 = (col+minDistBtwLocMax < scratch.cols ? col+minDistBtwLocMax : scratch.cols-1);
            for (int r = r0; r <= r1; r++) {
                for (int c = c0; c <= c1; c++) {
                    if (vdist(Point2DMake(r, c),Point2DMake(row, col)) <= minDistBtwLocMax) {
                        scratch.at<float>(r,c) = 0.0;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return nFoundLocMax;
}
```

Comment: +1  for making a function with all possible options like distance btw max, no. of max, threshold values etc. Haven't looked into the computations efficiency yet. Will let u know if there are any issues related to that.

Comment: Where are "vdist" and "Point2DMake" from?

Comment: You have to implement those yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The first question to answer would be what is "local" in your opinion. The answer may well be a square window (say 3x3 or 5x5) or circular window of a certain radius. You can then scan over the entire image with the window centered at each pixel and pick the highest value in the window.

See [this](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00053000000000000000) for how to access pixel values in OpenCV.

Comment: see my comment in the accepted answer. This method is not working. Consider an 100x100 image with greyvalue(x,y) = x+y. There is only one maximum at [99,99]. A sliding window would always find a local maximum in the lower right corner. Your method would basically return almost every pixel as a local maximum.

Answer (score 1):

> This is very fast method.  It stored founded maxima in a vector of
>   Points.

```
vector <Point> GetLocalMaxima(const cv::Mat Src,int MatchingSize, int Threshold, int GaussKernel  )
{  
  vector <Point> vMaxLoc(0); 

  if ((MatchingSize % 2 == 0) || (GaussKernel % 2 == 0)) // MatchingSize and GaussKernel have to be "odd" and > 0
  {
    return vMaxLoc;
  }

  vMaxLoc.reserve(100); // Reserve place for fast access 
  Mat ProcessImg = Src.clone();
  int W = Src.cols;
  int H = Src.rows;
  int SearchWidth  = W - MatchingSize;
  int SearchHeight = H - MatchingSize;
  int MatchingSquareCenter = MatchingSize/2;

  if(GaussKernel > 1) // If You need a smoothing
  {
    GaussianBlur(ProcessImg,ProcessImg,Size(GaussKernel,GaussKernel),0,0,4);
  }
  uchar* pProcess = (uchar *) ProcessImg.data; // The pointer to image Data 

  int Shift = MatchingSquareCenter * ( W + 1);
  int k = 0;

  for(int y=0; y < SearchHeight; ++y)
  { 
    int m = k + Shift;
    for(int x=0;x < SearchWidth ; ++x)
    {
      if (pProcess[m++] >= Threshold)
      {
        Point LocMax;
        Mat mROI(ProcessImg, Rect(x,y,MatchingSize,MatchingSize));
        minMaxLoc(mROI,NULL,NULL,NULL,&LocMax);
        if (LocMax.x == MatchingSquareCenter && LocMax.y == MatchingSquareCenter)
        { 
          vMaxLoc.push_back(Point( x+LocMax.x,y + LocMax.y )); 
          // imshow("W1",mROI);cvWaitKey(0); //For gebug              
        }
      }
    }
    k += W;
  }
  return vMaxLoc; 
}
```

Comment: it only gives negative X and Y

Comment: Although the idea is good and fast, your code doesn't work for features located at the bottom and right edges of the image. This is possibly because your pProcess[m++] will not get to the bottom and right edges, and if the threshold has not been triggered, it will not give a result, while near those edges the threshold might indeed be higher, but it will never trigger. The solution here is to increase the SearchWidth and searchHeight and then to some sanitation on your crop rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple solution.

In this example, if you are trying to find 2 results of a matchTemplate function with a minimum distance from each other.

```
    cv::Mat result;
    matchTemplate(search, target, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
    float score1;
    cv::Point displacement1 = MinMax(result, score1);
    cv::circle(result, cv::Point(displacement1.x+result.cols/2 , displacement1.y+result.rows/2), 10, cv::Scalar(0), CV_FILLED, 8, 0);
    float score2;
    cv::Point displacement2 = MinMax(result, score2);
```

where

```
cv::Point MinMax(cv::Mat &result, float &score)
{
    double minVal, maxVal;
    cv::Point  minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;

    minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, cv::Mat());
    matchLoc.x = minLoc.x - result.cols/2;
    matchLoc.y = minLoc.y - result.rows/2;
    return minVal;
}
```

The process is:

1. Find global Minimum using minMaxLoc
2. Draw a filled white circle around global minimum using min distance between minima as radius
3. Find another minimum

The the scores can be compared to each other to determine, for example, the certainty of the match,

Answer (score 1):

To find more than just the global minimum and maximum try using this function from `skimage`:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.peak_local_max

You can parameterize the minimum distance between peaks, too. And more. To find minima, use negated values (take care of the array type though, `255-image` could do the trick).

Answer (score 0):

You can go over each pixel and test if it is a local maxima. Here is how I would do it.
The input is assumed to be type CV_32FC1

```
#include <vector>//std::vector
#include <algorithm>//std::sort
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

//structure for maximal values including position
struct SRegionalMaxPoint
{
    SRegionalMaxPoint():
        values(-FLT_MAX),
        row(-1),
        col(-1)
    {}
    float values;
    int row;
    int col;
    //ascending order
    bool operator()(const SRegionalMaxPoint& a, const SRegionalMaxPoint& b)
    {   
        return a.values < b.values;
    }   
};

//checks if pixel is local max
bool isRegionalMax(const float* im_ptr, const int& cols )
{
    float center = *im_ptr;
    bool is_regional_max = true;
    im_ptr -= (cols + 1);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ++ii, im_ptr+= (cols-3))
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < 3; ++jj, im_ptr++)
        {
            if (ii != 1 || jj != 1)
            {
                is_regional_max &= (center > *im_ptr);
            }
        }
    }
    return is_regional_max;
}

void imregionalmax(
    const cv::Mat& input, 
    std::vector<SRegionalMaxPoint>& buffer)
{
    //find local max - top maxima
    static const int margin = 1;
    const int rows = input.rows;
    const int cols = input.cols;
    for (int i = margin; i < rows - margin; ++i)
    {
        const float* im_ptr = input.ptr<float>(i, margin);
        for (int j = margin; j < cols - margin; ++j, im_ptr++)
        {
            //Check if pixel is local maximum
            if ( isRegionalMax(im_ptr, cols ) )
            {
                cv::Rect roi = cv::Rect(j - margin, i - margin, 3, 3);
                cv::Mat subMat = input(roi);

                float val = *im_ptr;
                //replace smallest value in buffer
                if ( val > buffer[0].values )
                {
                    buffer[0].values = val;
                    buffer[0].row    = i;
                    buffer[0].col    = j;
                    std::sort(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), SRegionalMaxPoint());
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

For testing the code you can try this:

```
cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat::zeros(15, 15, CV_32FC1);
temp.at<float>(7, 7) = 1;
temp.at<float>(3, 5) = 6;
temp.at<float>(8, 10) = 4;
temp.at<float>(11, 13) = 7;
temp.at<float>(10, 3) = 8;
temp.at<float>(7, 13) = 3;

vector<SRegionalMaxPoint> buffer_(5);
imregionalmax(temp, buffer_);

cv::Mat debug;
cv::cvtColor(temp, debug, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
for (auto it = buffer_.begin(); it != buffer_.end(); ++it)
{
    circle(debug, cv::Point(it->col, it->row), 1, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
}
```

This solution does not take plateaus into account so it is not exactly the same as matlab's imregionalmax()