# SANITYCHECK and maxUsedValInHistogramData

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm trying to reimplement matlab `imregionalmax()` in C++ with openCV, i did search on the site and found some interesting answers here [Find local maxima in grayscale image using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550290/find-local-maxima-in-grayscale-image-using-opencv)  and the best one so far belongs to Doga Siyli, but there are 2 "weird" functions. The first one is: `SANITYCHECK(squareSize,3,1)` and the other one is : `maxUsedValInHistogramData(dst,false);`  .
(by "weird" i mean i don't think these two are OpenCV's function.)

My question is:

I replaced the `SANITYCHECK(squaresize,3,1)` with `assert(squareSize >= 3);` and `maxUsedValInHistogramData(dst,false);` with `minmaxLoc` but the program didn't work ,especially the second one because `minmaxLoc` return global value while Doga's intention is to find the local values.

So how do i make the code work ?

I am new to C++ and OpenCV,and i'm still learning,any help willl be greatly appreciated.

Here is his code for a closer look( he did explain it quite clear)

```
    void localMaxima(cv::Mat src, cv::Mat &dst, int squareSize)
{
if (squareSize == 0)
{
    dst = src.clone();
    return;
}

Mat m0;
dst = src.clone();
Point maxLoc(0, 0);

//1.Be sure to have at least 3x3 for at least looking at 1 pixel close neighbours
//  Also the window must be <odd>x<odd>
SANITYCHECK(squareSize, 3, 1);
int sqrCenter = (squareSize - 1) / 2;

//2.Create the localWindow mask to get things done faster
//  When we find a local maxima we will multiply the subwindow with this MASK
//  So that we will not search for those 0 values again and again
Mat localWindowMask = Mat::zeros(Size(squareSize, squareSize), CV_8U);//boolean
localWindowMask.at<unsigned char>(sqrCenter, sqrCenter) = 1;

//3.Find the threshold value to threshold the image
//this function here returns the peak of histogram of picture
//the picture is a thresholded picture it will have a lot of zero values in it
//so that the second boolean variable says :
//  (boolean) ? "return peak even if it is at 0" : "return peak discarding 0"
int thrshld = maxUsedValInHistogramData(dst, false); 
threshold(dst, m0, thrshld, 1, THRESH_BINARY);

//4.Now delete all thresholded values from picture
dst = dst.mul(m0);

//put the src in the middle of the big array
for (int row = sqrCenter; row<dst.size().height - sqrCenter; row++)
    for (int col = sqrCenter; col<dst.size().width - sqrCenter; col++)
    {
        //1.if the value is zero it can not be a local maxima
        if (dst.at<unsigned char>(row, col) == 0)
            continue;
        //2.the value at (row,col) is not 0 so it can be a local maxima point
        m0 = dst.colRange(col - sqrCenter, col + sqrCenter + 1).rowRange(row - sqrCenter, row + sqrCenter + 1);
        minMaxLoc(m0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &maxLoc);
        //if the maximum location of this subWindow is at center
        //it means we found the local maxima
        //so we should delete the surrounding values which lies in the subWindow area
        //hence we will not try to find if a point is at localMaxima when already found a neighbour was
        if ((maxLoc.x == sqrCenter) && (maxLoc.y == sqrCenter))
        {
            m0 = m0.mul(localWindowMask);
            //we can skip the values that we already made 0 by the above function
            col += sqrCenter;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `maxUsedValInHistogramData` function is used to improve computation time by defining a threshold `thrshld`.Then `cv::threshold` is used to set all the pixel of the dst image under `thrshld` to zero.

According to the explanation, the threshold is defined by the histogram max. This method is efficient, because a large part of the image, set to zero, is skipped:

```
if (dst.at<unsigned char>(row, col) == 0)
    continue;
```

However it also mean that the local maxima under `thrshld` are not detected

You can remove these three lines, and the function should work correctly but slower:

```
int thrshld = maxUsedValInHistogramData(dst, false); 
threshold(dst, m0, thrshld, 1, THRESH_BINARY);
dst = dst.mul(m0);
```

or write a function that detect the histogram maxima of the input image

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it.